# How to get audio driver for compaq c700?

Tags: windows, drivers, laptop, audio

Initially i have audio driver and its works fine.But some times speaker was clear.So one of my friend installed some audio driver,after that totally disabled the volume.

For that reason, i also tried to get audio driver and installed many times.Now i don't know many drivers .inf in my laptop.from device manager i have deleted the audio driver's,below i have attached the screen shot yours kind reference.

Please help me to get audio drivers.First, i need to remove the unwanted drivers .inf files from laptop then i have to install the new audio driver.

Experts,please suggest me to get audio driver without reinstall the OS.

Details:

Compaq c700 (i don't know model number)
windows xp sp2
p/n : KT188PA#ACJ

I appreciate your help.

Comment: HP doesn't have sound card drivers on their website for that laptop. You're going to have to figure out what chipset it has and download the drivers from the manufacturer. You'd be better off finding someone who knows what they're doing to do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Install this Microsoft UAA driver first (XP sp1 and sp2 only)
http://cid-3f10d7c1771f7efe.skydrive.live.com/self.aspx/Public/MS-UAA%20for%20XP.zip

Then install this Modded Audio driver to work on that model and XP

http://cid-3f10d7c1771f7efe.office.live.com/self.aspx/Public/Conexant%20SmartAudio%5E_221%5E_XP.zip

.